# Rails 2 to Rails 3 conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

```
class ForumMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def new_post(user,post)  
    @subject        = "New post on #{post.topic.title} from #{SITE_NAME}"  
    @recipients     = user.profile.email  
    @body['user']   = user   
    @body['post']   = post  
    @from           = MAILER_FROM_ADDRESS  
    @sent_on        = Time.new  
    @content_type = "text/html"  

  end
end
```

Please help me to convert this Rails 2.xx code to Rails 3.x.x

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you successfully looked at mailer code in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read te following three posts all taken from [a rails demo](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts) then you should get somewhere:

- [#43 A Contact Form - Rails Engines, The Enginex Gem and The MailForm Gem](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/43)
- [#44 A Contact Form - Implementation](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/44)
- [#45 A Contact Form - Rails Generators](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/45)

I also recommend [this post](http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html) too